# Total Amount in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am newbie in XSLT.I am Using XSLT(XML to XML).Please check my code -

Input XML -

```
 <FCRep>
      <AirInfo>
          <AdtTransFee>0.000</AdtTransFee>
          <ChdTransFee>0.000</ChdTransFee>
          <InfTransFee>0.000</InfTransFee>
          <AutoCharges grandTotal="30.000">
            <Charge name="SAFI" operator="+" isSupplierFee="TRUE" ApplyOn="BaseFare">
              <Adult>5.000</Adult>
              <Child>5.000</Child>
              <Infant>5.000</Infant>
              <DBAmount type="fixed" />
              <Total>15.000</Total>
            </Charge>
            <Charge name="APC" operator="+" isSupplierFee="TRUE" ApplyOn="BaseFare">
              <Adult>5.000</Adult>
              <Child>5.000</Child>
              <Infant>5.000</Infant>
              <DBAmount type="fixed" />
              <Total>15.000</Total>
            </Charge>
            <Charge name="Supplier Fee" operator="+" isSupplierFee="True" ApplyOn="BaseFare+YQ">
              <Adult>0.000</Adult>
              <Child>0.000</Child>
              <Infant>0.000</Infant>
              <DBAmount type="False">0</DBAmount>
              <Total>0.000</Total>
            </Charge>
          </AutoCharges>
      </AirInfo>
    </FCRep>
```

XSLT -

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="root" select="FareRules" />
  <xsl:variable name="journey" select="FareRules/JournyType" />
  <xsl:variable name ="nOfADT" select="FareRules/noa" />
  <xsl:variable name ="nOfCHD" select="FareRules/noc" />
  <xsl:variable name ="nOfINF" select="FareRules/noi" />
  <xsl:variable name="searchType" select="FareRules/SearchType" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <FlightDetailRule>

      <xsl:element name="AirInfo">

        <FareDetails>
          <xsl:if test="$nOfADT > 0">
            <xsl:element name="PaxType">
              <xsl:attribute name="Type">
                <xsl:value-of select="'ADT'"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <NoOfPax>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nOfADT"/>
              </NoOfPax>
              <BFare>
                <xsl:value-of select="ABP"/>
              </BFare>
              <Tax>
                <xsl:value-of select="ATax"/>
              </Tax>
              <Yq>
                <xsl:value-of select="AdultYQ"/>
              </Yq>

              <xsl:element name="OthChg">
                <xsl:attribute name="ChgTotal">
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="AutoCharges/Charge">
                  <xsl:element name="Chg">
                    <xsl:attribute name="NM">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Adult"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:element name="Chg">
                  <xsl:attribute name="NM">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'TransFee'"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="AdtTransFee"/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>

          <xsl:if test="$nOfCHD > 0">
            <xsl:element name="PaxType">
              <xsl:attribute name="Type">
                <xsl:value-of select="'CHD'"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <NoOfPax>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nOfCHD"/>
              </NoOfPax>
              <BFare>
                <xsl:value-of select="CBP"/>
              </BFare>
              <Tax>
                <xsl:value-of select="CTax"/>
              </Tax>
              <Yq>
                <xsl:value-of select="ChildYQ"/>
              </Yq>

              <xsl:element name="OthChg">
                <xsl:attribute name="ChgTotal">
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="AutoCharges/Charge">
                  <xsl:element name="Chg">
                    <xsl:attribute name="NM">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Child"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:element name="Chg">
                  <xsl:attribute name="NM">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'TransFee'"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ChdTransFee"/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>

            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>

          <xsl:if test="$nOfINF > 0">
            <xsl:element name="PaxType">
              <xsl:attribute name="Type">
                <xsl:value-of select="'INF'"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <NoOfPax>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nOfINF"/>
              </NoOfPax>
              <BFare>
                <xsl:value-of select="IBP"/>
              </BFare>
              <Tax>
                <xsl:value-of select="ITax"/>
              </Tax>
              <Yq>
                <xsl:value-of select="InfantYQ"/>
              </Yq>

              <xsl:element name="OthChg">
                <xsl:attribute name="ChgTotal">
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="AutoCharges/Charge">
                  <xsl:element name="Chg">
                    <xsl:attribute name="NM">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Infant"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:element name="Chg">
                  <xsl:attribute name="NM">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'TransFee'"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="InfTransFee"/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>

            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>

        </FareDetails>

      </xsl:element>
    </FlightDetailRule>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML -

```
 <FlightDetailRule>
      <AirInfo>
          <FareDetails>
            <PaxType Type="ADT">
              <NoOfPax>1</NoOfPax>
              <BFare>12.000</BFare>
              <Tax>53.200</Tax>
              <Yq>0.0000</Yq>
              <OthChg ChgTotal="">
                <Chg NM="SAFI">5.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="APC">5.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="Supplier Fee">0.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="TransFee">0.000</Chg>
              </OthChg>
            </PaxType>
            <PaxType Type="CHD">
              <NoOfPax>1</NoOfPax>
              <BFare>12.000</BFare>
              <Tax>53.200</Tax>
              <Yq>0.0000</Yq>
              <OthChg ChgTotal="">
                <Chg NM="SAFI">5.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="APC">5.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="Supplier Fee">0.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="TransFee">0.000</Chg>
              </OthChg>
            </PaxType>
            <PaxType Type="INF">
              <NoOfPax>1</NoOfPax>
              <BFare>7.000</BFare>
              <Tax>10.300</Tax>
              <Yq>0.0000</Yq>
              <OthChg ChgTotal="">
                <Chg NM="SAFI">5.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="APC">5.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="Supplier Fee">0.000</Chg>
                <Chg NM="TransFee">0.000</Chg>
              </OthChg>
            </PaxType>
          </FareDetails>
      </AirInfo>
    </FlightDetailRule>
```

My output is coming fine but I also want **ChgTotal** attribute in **OthChg** nodes.
Please suggest me that how I can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have empty ChgTotal attribute in OthChg element...

Comment: Yes Kirill.that is what I want.:)

Comment: ChgTotal is the total of the all Chg node value.

Comment: I've tested your stylesheet and (as I thought in advance) it does not produce the result you are showing. This is obvious, since your stylesheet does not match any element in the input document. So, you provided wrong input, or wrong stylesheet or what??

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is appropriate here to use the standard XPath function [`sum()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-sum) like this**:

**Your code**:

```
              <xsl:element name="OthChg">
                <xsl:attribute name="ChgTotal">
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="AutoCharges/Charge">
                  <xsl:element name="Chg">
                    <xsl:attribute name="NM">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Adult"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:element name="Chg">
                  <xsl:attribute name="NM">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'TransFee'"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="AdtTransFee"/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
```

**Correct code**:

```
            <OthChg ChgTotal="{sum(AutoCharges/Charge/Adult)+AdtTransFee}">
                <xsl:for-each select="AutoCharges/Charge">
                  <Chg NM="{@name}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Adult"/>
                  </Chg>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <Chg NM="TransFee">
                  <xsl:value-of select="AdtTransFee"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </OthChg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at XPath `number sum(node-set)` function.